# The request is not a valid WS-Federation protocol message

Tags: 2013-sp1, cme

On our Tridion 2013 SP1 environment we get the following error message regularly.
What can be the issue here?

[image]

It occurs when browsing through the CMS.

UPDATE:

The issue dissappears when clearing cookies. I don't think there is something wrong with Tridion itself.

I will investigate further.

UPDATE 23-10

Following two cookies are responsible for the error:

[image]

Those cookies are set on another website with the same domain. Tridion is on a subdomain of that website.

When those two cookies are set, all requests in Tridion gresult in a 400 or a 500 error. When I remove OR empty the cookie values, the issue is fixed.

**REAL ISSUE**

An idea came into my mind. I created a test cookie with a comma in it and... Tridion gave the same errors:

[image]

So it looks like Tridion can't handle cookies with comma's and  braces. Is there a fix for?

Comment: Can you **edit** your question and provide some more details about your setup, like are you using SSO, or what Active Directories do you use for your user accounts etc.

Comment: Indeed, the error message hints at some SSO system intercepting the request to the CME backend service. It apparently wants to use the WS-Federation protocol (which is not supported by the CME frontend).

Comment: Hi Bart, Rick. Thank you for your replies. I found out it has something to do with cookies. If I clear cookies the CMS is working again.

Comment: @BartKoopman and Rick, found the real issue! Tridion is going crazy when a cookie is set with a comma or brace in it.

Comment: @PetervanderLugt please self answer your question with your findings, and then after a few days you can accept the answer so the question will be marked as solved.

Comment: @BartKoopman I found the issue, but not the solution (only a workaround). Is it correct that Tridion doens't accept cookies with a comma in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally we found the rootcause. The Web Application Proxy (WAP) is very strict in which kind of requests it accepts. According to the standards, a comma value is not allowed, see: https://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25387340/is-comma-a-valid-character-in-cookie-value.

So the WAP is blocking all requests after a cookie with an not valid value is set.

So the issue has not to do with Tridion but with the WAP, which is part of our infrastructure. The WAP is not the rootcause, but a script which sets cookies which are not following the standard.